# Handling errors in React (Error Boundary, React-Query, Axios Interceptor)

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router, sentry, react-query

I have a Create React App (that uses `react-router` v6) that is setup the following way to communicate with the API.

At the top level - I wrapped my app in an `ErrorBoundary` (`Sentry.ErrorBoundary`).

When fetching the API, the front-end calls a `useQuery` method from `react-query` (which uses an axios instance to fetch the requested API URL).

***But how do I handle an error 404 or 500 from axios?***

Currently the `ErrorBoundary` renders an `ErrorPage` that is blocking the UI. I'm trying to find a better way that don't block the UI.

The way I see it, I can handle errors in the following way:

1. using axios interceptor directly - but currently it's in a separate file and don't use useNavigate() of React Router - so either I use window to redirect to `/404` or `/500` or I wrap it inside a `React.Context` (itself wrapped in my React Router context) so that it can use `useNavigate()` inside of it from `react-router` to redirect to `/404` or `/500`.
2. using `onError` handler from react-query (directly inside my `QueryClient` config) that will be passed an `AxiosError` and redirect to `/404` or `/500` based on axios error response status
3. Using the error object that comes from `Sentry.ErrorBoundary` and render a different UI based on the error response status from axios

Solution 1 and 2 will leverage `useNavigate()` by `react-router` to redirect (or window.pathname) but I'm not satisfied with these... The solution 3 is more interesting for me (as I can have a 404 UI without changing pathname!) but the solution 3 does not handle the error (it'll be uncaught)...

Any recommendation or better idea?

I haven't found that much regarding handling errors in an SPA - thank you for your time :)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?